# How to make a custom Filtered Selection field for a Many2one field?

Tags: xml, filter, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I'm currently working with Odoo 10. I would like to make a new filter for a many2one field. I need to make a custom filter selection field. The user shouldn´t be able to choose from the list values by typing what he's looking for. This is my code in template.xml file:

```xml
<t t-extend="ListView">
    <t t-jquery=".o_list_view" t-operation="before">   
        <select onclick="My function ">
            <option>Valeur 1</option>
            <option>Valeur 2</option>
        </select>
    </t>
</t>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if I understood your question well, but I will give it a try

You don't need to extend the xml template of the form. You just need to add the many2one field as any other field with the `widget="selection"`. And if you want to filter data just add a `domain` to that field. Check this example:

```xml
<field name="journal_id" domain="[('type','in',['sale','sale_refund'])]" widget="selection" />
```

**Note**: Check [**this link**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#inheritance) if you want more information about modifying and inheriting forms.